# How to change drag cursor by dragging in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I have a widget that accepts drop. The object which is dragged in this example can be any pdf or text file. The requirement is when the dragged object goes inside my widget, the cursor should be changed into another form.
I did some search here, and there is a way to do it `setDragCursor`, but this function is of `QDrag`. I did not create the dragged widget myself and from `dropEnterEvent` and `dropMoveEvent` I don't know how to change the cursor.

DragWidget.h

```
#ifndef DRAGWIDGET_H
#define DRAGWIDGET_H

#include <QFrame>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QDragMoveEvent>

class DragWidget : public QFrame
{
public:
    DragWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override;
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // DRAGWIDGET_H
```

DragWidget.cpp

```
#include "dragwidget.h"
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QDebug>

DragWidget::DragWidget(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent)
{
    setMinimumSize(300, 300);
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken | QFrame::StyledPanel);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void DragWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    const QMimeData *mimeData = event->mimeData();
    if ( mimeData->hasText() || mimeData->hasFormat( "application/json" ) )
    {
        qDebug()<<mimeData->text();
    }
}

void DragWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "dragwidget.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    DragWidget *m_dragWidget=nullptr;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_dragWidget = new DragWidget(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

With the code above, the mouse cursor off course does not change
[image]

Do you guys have any idea about this?

Comment: This is probably hard to achieve in pure Qt (and platform independent). You had to access the `QDrag` object via `event->source()` but it returns `nullptr` for drag events triggered from other applications.

Comment: FYI: [dragEnterEvent from external file issue](https://forum.qt.io/topic/70983/dragenterevent-from-external-file-issue/11)

Comment: @Scheff: thanks for your idea. Actually I have tried this in `dragEnterEvent` `QDrag *drag = new QDrag( event->source() );
         drag->setDragCursor( myPixMap, Qt::MoveAction );` but it does not work. :(

Comment: I've tried this as well (on Windows 10) but I failed also. ;-) I also had a look into the [github repo of Clementine](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine) (as recommended in the Qt forum Q/A) but I couldn't find anything significant. Maybe, I didn't dig deep enough or there is simply nothing like claimed by that OP.